# android market "Upload an .apk file" keeps failing, when trying to replace current apk

Tags: android, publish, apk

I have a draft apk, unpublished, up on the android market store and I've recently made a some fixes and minor enhancements.  Every time, I try to 'replace' the current version, I get a terse message of "The server could not process your apk. Try again." towards the very end of download process.

At first, I thought it might be flaky internet connections or such.   But now, I'm suspecting it may be something is wrong in my apk file.

I have the exact same manifest file, used the same build and sign process.  File is just under 6MBs.  I've tried doing this using both chrome and firefox.

Suggestions?

Comment: I recently had the same problem. I deleted my draft and uploaded a new.

Comment: `I have the exact same manifest file` - you must increase your version number. If you've already done that, it could be a problem on Google's end... I know I've had similar unexplained uploading issues, and they've gone away with as much explanation.

Comment: @mah - I was wondering about the version number, but I am not making an upgrade, merely updating the current one that has not been published.  Would I still need to update the version number?

Comment: You need a new versionCode every time the app is uploaded. The versionName does not have to change and is what you should be displaying to the customer. versionCode is what the market uses to keep track of different uploads of your code and you literally cannot upload any changes to the apk without first ensuring that the apk you are uploading has a versionCode greater then the existing one.

Comment: Well, I updated the versionCode number and same problem.  Waah. waiting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem last week. Just waited a few hours, and tried again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems replacing an unpublished apk is still broken. Removing and then uploading the apk works, but in the process it also removes in-app products associated with the application and you have to create them all over again each time. Not cool when you're doing all this to understand and test in-app billing (and you don't want to trust Google's in-app billing documentation as far as I know).